# Why does the Data.String.IsString typeclass only define one conversion?

Tags: string, haskell

Why does the Haskell base package only define the `IsString` class to have a conversion from `String` to 'like-string' value, and not define the inverse transformation, from 'like-string' value to `String`?

The class should be defined as:

```
class IsString a where
    fromString :: String -> a
    toString :: a -> String
```

ref: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-String.html

Comment: I do not know Haskell, but you could likely create your own inverse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is IMHO that `IsString`'s primary purpose is to be used for string literals in Haskell source code (or (E)DSLs -- see also [Paradise: A two-stage DSL embedded in Haskell](http://urchin.earth.li/~ganesh/icfp08.pdf)) via the `OverloadedStrings` language extension in an analogous way to how other polymorphic literals work (e.g. via `fromRational` for floating point literals or `fromInteger` for integer literals)

The term `IsString` might be a bit misleading, as it suggests that the type-class represents string-like structures, whereas it's really just to denote types which have a quoted-string-representation in Haskell source code.

Comment: Note also that there are some types in packages like mysql-simple that use OverloadedStrings (rather than a more safe method like QuasiQuotation) to provide an easier way to construct values, but the inverse may not always be possible (or unique).

Comment: I think about the problem when I used the OverloadedStrings flag with Aeson, It removes all the pack "name". But with another context y already need to have unpack ByteString to String.

Answer (score 8):

If you desire to use `toString :: a -> String`, I think you're simply forgetting about `show :: a -> String`, or more properly `Show a => show :: a -> String`.

If you want to operate on a type both having a `:: a -> String`  *and* `:: String -> a`, you can simply put those type-class constraints on the functions.

```
doubleConstraintedFunction :: Show a, IsString a => a -> .. -> .. -> a
```

We carefully note that we avoid defining type classes having a set of functions that can as well be split into two subclasses. Therefor we don't put `toString` in `IsString`.

Finally, I must also mention about `Read`, which provides `Read a => String -> a`. You use `read` and `show` for very simple serialization. `fromString` from `IsString` has a different purpose, it's useful with the language pragma `OverloadedStrings`, then you can very conveniently insert code like `"This is not a string" :: Text`. (`Text` is a (efficient) data-structure for Strings)

Comment: the problem with `show :: Show a => a -> String` is that it doesn't just perform a type conversion to a `String` but it also adds quotes and character escapes to provide a string representation in the Haskell grammar. Thus, `fromString . show` is not equivalent to `id` as you seem to suggest. Have you actually tried your `backAndForth` function?

Comment: I did not suggest that it's equivalent (it is not), I wanted to demonstrate that a function can have multiple type constraints. But I realize that `backAndForth` is a very misleading name, however I compensated that with the comment in the code. Anyway I edited the post to be even clearer.

Comment: I also removed the implementation and renamed the function, I agree that it is mostly confusing.